# FBSDKLikeControl opening facebook instead coming back to app

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdklikecontrol

Trying to add facebook native like button to my app. its only opening my page then after tapping ok or unlike its opening facebook homepage instead of coming back to the applciation

```
        FBSDKLikeControl *likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] init];
        [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/a2zTwoWheels/";
        likeButton.center = self.view.center;
        [fbPopupView addSubview:likeButton];
```

Please don't suggest existing questions with callback solutions , tried all before posting this question

Comment: are you register your app in develper portal on facebook

Comment: yes.. application successfully reviewed by facebook